# What do you call the tags in Subversion and CVS that add automatic content?

Tags: svn, tags, cvs

Things like `$log$` and `$version$` which add data upon check-in to the file. I'm interested in seeing the other ones and what information they can provide, but I can't get much info unless I know what they are called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both Subversion and CVS call them `Keywords`.

[Have a look in the SVN manual here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3) (scroll down to **svn:keywords**) or [here for CVS](http://badgertronics.com/writings/cvs/keywords.html).

Answer (score 1):

In SVN these are simply called "properties". You can read about them in the SVN book:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html

---

Err, so, are they called properties or keywords? Oh, I see. In SVN you can associate arbitrary metadata, called "properties", with versioned files; some of the properties you can set are to set up keyword substitution in the files themselves.

Answer (score 0):

These are Keyword substitutions. The link to SVNBook 1.8 is here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html.

Subversion's built-in keywords are:

- Date / LastChangedDate
- Revision / Rev / LastChangedRevision
- Author / LastChangedBy
- HeadURL / URL
- Id

The keywords are case sensitive, and remember to surround them with $.